# How to install GSAP with bonus plugins locally?

Tags: gsap

I have done the installation steps. I tried every way but I can't run it in HTML file. Even if I throw the "gsap" file in the "node_modules" section and call it with the <script> tag, it doesn't work.

This is how I call "all.js" in HTML file. Tried all other ways too.

```
<script src="src/all.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I want to use all plugins locally in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <script src="path-to-my-scripts/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="path-to-my-scripts/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Okay, I solved it. It is necessary to write the "min.js" files, not the "all.js" file directly.